# Data Manipulation and Structures in R

Tags: r, data-structures

I have an 'Exp' data set which looks like this:

```
  Locals   Res   Ind
1    112 7.865 4.248
2    113 4.248 5.666
3    114 5.666 2.444
4    115 2.444 7.865
5    116 7.865 4.248
6    117 4.248 6.983
7    118 5.666 3.867
8    119 2.444 2.987
```

And I have another data set called 'Com' as below:

```
113 112 113
112 114 119
116 118 119
118 118 119
117 117 119
117 117 119
```

Using `Exp_rem <- lapply(Exp[-1],function(x) structure(x[match(as.matrix  (  Com),Exp[,1])],.Dim=dim(Com)))` I created a list. 
Such that `Exp_rem$Res` is as below:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 4.248 7.865 4.248
[2,] 7.865 5.666 2.444
[3,] 7.865 5.666 2.444
[4,] 5.666 5.666 2.444
[5,] 4.248 4.248 2.444
[6,] 4.248 4.248 2.444
```

And `Exp_rem$Ind` is as below:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 5.666 4.248 5.666
[2,] 4.248 2.444 2.987
[3,] 4.248 3.867 2.987
[4,] 3.867 3.867 2.987
[5,] 6.983 6.983 2.987
[6,] 6.983 6.983 2.987
```

I am looking to sum through the `Exp_rem` list to get aggregate values. For eg. `113` will be `4.248` and `4.248`(from `Exp_rem$Res`), `5.666` and `5.666`(from `Exp_rem$Ind`), giving a total of `19.828`. The idea is - can we sum across the `Exp_rem` list as if it were a three dimensional data frame and by creating an object of `113`, `114`, `115` and so forth - such that the output looks like this:

```
Loc Value
113 19.828
114 8.11
116 12.113
117 44.924
118 28.599
119 14.935
```

What is the best way to apply it to a large set data with several lists. Is there a way by not using original Exp data set to produce the values. Thank you.

Comment: Please give `dput()` of your list, at least the first rows of these cells mentioned, so that we can produce a solution. See [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: do.call( "+", lapply(lst, function(x) tapply(x, unlist(Com),sum)))

Comment: tapply(unlist(lst),rep(unlist(Com),2),sum)